# SQL Server on Vmware ESx (update 2)

Tags: sql-server, networking, vmware, vmware-tools

I have a strange behavior. I have a Windows Server 2012 machine installed on VMWARE ESX 6 (update 2) which has a database containing one table (with 5 millions of rows).

The server is a Windows 2012, SQL Server 2014 enterprise, 80Gb of RAM (64gb reserved for SQL Server) and a 10gb network card (with the VMXNET3 ethernet adapater).

When a I do a simple `select * from table`, from a physical machine trough SQL Server Management Studio to the server, it retrieves the entire table (3,4 gb on network) with a bandwidth of 256mbps per second.

When I run the same query from a another VM (also from SQL Server Management Studio to the same database server), it tops to 70mpbs. There are no firewall or other stuff between the two machines.

Do you have any ideas?

Regards,

Patrice

Comment: This is likely something to do with the vSwitch... would need more details about the differences in the Physical machine and the other VM you queried from... is the VM on the same host, are they on the same VM Network? Are you using NSX? Different VLANs? There are a lot of variables that could be causing this